# Examples of dialog UX concepts?

Tags: gui-design, notification, popup, dialog, mockup

I want to design an easy-to-use set of dialogs for my users to get notified of anything & possibly interact with my app via those dialog boxes.

A "Dialog box" is also known as "Popup", "Confirmation box", "Alert", "Prompt", "Notification" & more.

As for [this other question on login forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93651/what-are-your-favorite-login-forms-ux-concepts/93652), I have been looking for mockups as a first phase, but I have found more fully designed & live examples. It's great but I'd like to have mockups in order to abstract away any complexity or distraction.

I expected to find more resources on mockups of dialogs since it's such a recurrent component: it's on almost every website/web-app. So let's try to help solve this, that'd be great if you can share your creations here or link to relevant web page(s).

Answer (score 1):

### Common requirements:

I have identified common requirements/patterns for the "dialog" concepts I came across.

1. OK and Cancel buttons
2. Close icon in top-right corner (same action as "cancel"?)
3. Hitting "escape" closes the prompt (same action as "cancel"?)
4. User can move popup around using drag n drop
5. Confirmation dialog must be enforced

   - by ticking a checkbox
   - by typing text
   - by captcha-like process
   - etc..

---

### Mockups

I have "translated" to mockups some of those `fully designed & live examples` mentioned in the question & added some of the concepts from the "common requirements" mentioned above.

Feel free to add your contribution in an additional answer. Thanks.

#### Mockups of basic dialogs

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnGkoq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

#### Mockups of dialogs with "checkbox enforced confirmations"

Enforced confirmation means that the user do an additional action - tick a checkbox in this case - to reach the next step.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRUEPd.png)</sup>

#### Mockups of dialogs with "text-box enforced confirmations"

Enforced confirmation means that the user do an additional action - by entering text in a text-box in this case - to reach the next step.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj8vAS.png)</sup>

#### Mockup of "complex dialog"

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYIxAK.png)</sup>

---

### Related

https://github.com/hubspot/vex

http://codepen.io/cupofjoakim/pen/wEkag

http://codepen.io/matthewbeta/pen/rwhyo

http://codepen.io/adventuresinmissions/pen/nrhHF

http://codepen.io/nodws/pen/vELwJz

http://codepen.io/kushalpandya/pen/qhzwA

http://tympanus.net/Development/DialogEffects/

http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/